# short dump about generating selection screen

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I get the following error when I try to execute my SAP program using ABAP.

[image: Error Message]

Everything is activated and I have no syntax errors.

Help please.

Comment: Please pprovide a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can inspect much more in the dump. Try this. And also inspect the stacktrace and the field's content. By the way, what did the workbench tell You during activation?

Comment: You can further investigate this dump using the t-code ST22.

Comment: Did you try an extended syntax check?